# Can you apply for a PhD that requires an MSc when only 2/3 of MSc grades will be in by application time?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science, transcript-of-records

I am currently pursuing a Master's in CS in USA. This particular program will only be a year long since I did my undergrad at the same university and had some credits transferred over. I was researching Phd programs in Canada and they all require a Master's degree for admission. I wanted to know if I can apply right now as a Master's student for entry in Fall 2016?

My program will be over in Spring 2016. My application will contain only 2/3 of my Master's grades by the time of application. I know that you can apply for a Master's program in your last year of undergrad. Is it the same for Phd?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  When a degree is required prior to starting a program, that degree is needed in order to enrol, but not to apply.

Comment: What if prior to starting the Ph.D. program, one didn't manage to finish the ms degree?